# Date and time separator changes from a comma to "at" depending on Node version

Tags: node.js

I recently updated my local Node.js from v14.18.0 to v16.17.1 and I encountered an issue where a test case started failing because a date wasn't being formatted the expected way. I narrowed down the issue to a change in how my chosen formatting options get displayed depending on which version of Node.js I have installed.

Consider the following snippet:

```js
const format_options = {
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit',
    year: 'numeric',
    day: 'numeric',
    month: 'short'
}

const date = new Date('2022-09-28T12:00:00.000');
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', format_options).format(date));
// pre v16.17.0: Sep 28, 2022, 12:00 PM
// post v16.17.0: Sep 28, 2022, 12:00 PM

format_options.month = 'long';
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', format_options).format(date));
// pre v16.17.0: September 28, 2022, 12:00 PM
// post v16.17.0: September 28, 2022 at 12:00 PM
//                                  ^
```

I have not done an exhaustive comparison of Node.js versions, but it appears that starting sometime around v16.17.0 the format of the "long" month option changes the separator between the date and time from `,` to `at`. Based on the example documentation for [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat) this appears to be the expected behaviour, but given the results from my previous Node.js version I am assuming it wasn't always this way.

My question is why did this formatting behaviour change, and is there a way to restore the original behaviour (separating date and time with a `,`)?

Possible solutions include doing some sort of replacement on the output or formatting the date and time separately and then combining them with a custom separator, but I'm hoping there is a way to do it within the original single set of formatting options.

Comment: This [issue on Github](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/44454) from a month ago describes the same behaviour and has some suggestions as to why the formatting changed.